# What have I drilled into?

Tags: walls, drill

Was drilling into wall to hand a mirror and I got some trouble which ended with a large hole. Brown dust came out and now I’m not sure if I should’ve drilled into the wall.[image]

Comment: Does it click like metal when you tap something metal against it? My money is on a cast iron vent pipe.

Comment: Can you post another picture, farther out so we can see the big picture? How far did you drill into the wall? What size bit were you using?

Comment: Shine a light in there and see what's in there.

Comment: It looks like clay brick to me

Comment: You did a great job getting a clear photo of a small hole!

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of aggregate bound together with clay. Is there a chimney going up behind the wall? If yes, then you ruptured the flue and risk fumes coming into the house. If you have access to the basement, see if you can find what's going up around that area. Combustion pipe? Drainage pipe vent? Whatever it is, it must be fixed.

Comment: I’m in apartment complex, asked on the building board too.